# Android service won't stay alive

Tags: java, android, service, android-studio, android-service

My app has one service already that handles notifications, but I need a second one that runs persistent in the background listening for incoming data from the Pebble smartwatch.

However, for some reason, even though the service is declared in the Android manifest and will launch with the app, it closes immediately  and permanently.

I don't really want to use a foreground service, because I don't feel like I should have to. There are plenty of service that run quietly in the background in a persistent fashion like Facebook and Music Boss.

The service is being started in the main activity's `onCreate`, so why is my service being killed immediately?

From PebbleService.java:

```
package net.thevgc.quotes;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.getpebble.android.kit.PebbleKit;
import com.getpebble.android.kit.util.PebbleDictionary;

import java.util.UUID;

public class PebbleService extends Service {
    private PebbleKit.PebbleDataReceiver appMessageReciever;
    private static final int KEY_AUTHOR = 1;
    private static final int KEY_QUOTE = 0;
    private static final UUID WATCHAPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("18451441-8451-4418-4514-418451441845");

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        String[] extras = (String[]) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
        final String quote = extras[0];
        final String author = extras[1];

        // Define AppMessage behavior
        if (appMessageReciever == null) {
            appMessageReciever = new PebbleKit.PebbleDataReceiver(WATCHAPP_UUID) {

                @Override
                public void receiveData(Context context, int transactionId, PebbleDictionary data) {
                    // Always ACK
                    PebbleKit.sendAckToPebble(context, transactionId);

                    // Send KEY_QUOTE to Pebble
                    PebbleDictionary out = new PebbleDictionary();
                    out.addString(KEY_QUOTE, mainActivity.quote[0]);
                    out.addString(KEY_AUTHOR, mainActivity.quote[1]);
                    PebbleKit.sendDataToPebble(getApplicationContext(), WATCHAPP_UUID, out);
                }
            };

            // Add AppMessage capabilities
            PebbleKit.registerReceivedDataHandler(this, appMessageReciever);
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

From AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="PebbleService" />
```

**UPDATE:** Apparently the service is running somewhere, because I fiddled with the code some and now I'm getting a null pointer, but only when I close the main activity. I'm pretty sure it's getting relaunched and can't find the extra data it needs from the main activity because that's not the intent that started it. Which means I still have to use `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();` to get the string data I need.

**UPDATE 2:** Okay, I feel really bad for causing all this confusion. The service *is* running, but it's not showing up in my Settings > Apps > Running list, even under the parent activity. I know it's running, though, because it finally ticked what it was supposed to do. Guessing a weak Bluetooth connection. That being said, I'm still throwing a NullPointerException with the current code trying to receive the intent extras. I've [opened a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465082/passing-extras-from-activity-to-intent-throws-nullpointerexception) for that issue, though.

Comment: Doesn't look like your service does anything. Why would it stay alive?

Comment: sorry but have you started the service because there's no reason to be auto destroyed , what version of android you're using ?

Comment: Never instantiate activities like `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();`.

Comment: Use  `return START_STICKY;`

Comment: @FouadWahabi As I said in the OP, the service is started with the main activity's `onCreate`. I'm debugging on API 19.

Comment: @KNeerajLal didn't fix it.

Comment: @Simas How should I do it then?

Comment: Send your strings as intent extras.

Comment: @Simas without using `getIntent()` I'm not sure how I would, and that's been depreciated since API 13.

Comment: `onStartCommand` has an `Intent` parameter.

Comment: @Simas I think I figured a way out. But I still can't test if that's working because the service dies within the second it's opened.

Comment: Check your currently posted code. It can't be right as you're still using `mainActivity` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning `START_NOT_STICKY`, Android will stop your `Service` as soon as it returns from `onStartCommand()`. If you want your `Service` to stay alive then you need to return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`.

Also, your `Service` doesn't automatically launch with the app. It needs to be started by calling `startService()`.

Also, as someone noted in a comment, do not create Android components using `new`, like this:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

Only Android can properly instantiate components `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` and `Provider`, because they also need to have their `Context` set up.

Comment: I updated my question accordingly. While I get that it's bad practice or whatever the case to call intents using `new`, if I don't it throws an error. I have to call string data from one of my internal classes.

Comment: No, that is the wrong approach. You should pass the data from `MainActivity` to your `Service` in the `Intent` that you pass to `startService()`. The dependency you've got from `Service` to `Activity` is wrong.

Comment: I tried to do that with the intent extras, but it throws a NullPointerException, so I'm really not sure where to proceed from here.

Comment: Then you aren't doing it right. There's plenty of examples on Stackoverflow about how to pass data between an `Activity` and a `Service` using extras in an `Intent.

Comment: I've updated the OP again. I looked at one earlier but it's possible that I copied something down wrong. I'll take a second look.

Comment: You'll need to show the code you use to put the "data" extra into the `Intent`. In any case, if you want to pass a `String` array you should use `getStringArrayExtra()` instead of `getSerializableExtra()`.

Comment: I'll make a new post. I think that would be easier than trying to modify this one around a new problem.

Comment: Which, of course, I can't do for another 40 minutes.

Comment: Anyway, I guess in the meantime here's the code. http://paste.ubuntu.com/11373780/

Comment: If you add extras using `putExtra("quote", thing)` then you need to extract it like this: `String quote = intent.getStringExtra("quote")`

Comment: Yeah, I'm in the middle of refactoring some of the variable names. Those were the old ones. I think this will be a lot more helpful: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11373800/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465082/passing-extras-from-activity-to-intent-throws-nullpointerexception